# MongoDB extract value from array of objects into simple array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of documents that I initially set up like this:

```
{
  _id: "some_id",
  data: [
    {
      _id: "_id_foo",
      value: "foo"
    },
    {
      _id: "_id_bar",
      value: "bar"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, I realized I don't need the `value` field, so I can turn the array of objects into an array of strings `["_id_foo", "_id_bar"]`. I'm trying to build a pipeline to accomplish this, but I'm failing miserably.

If it's easier, I can also create a `data_new` array and delete the old one later.

Thanks!

Comment: Just use `$map` for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [map](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator and convert the array of objects to array of strings.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      data: {
        $map: {
          input: "$data",
          as: "data",
          in: "$$data._id"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zfxgvRYaLZ3)

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! I didn't know about `map`

Comment: If the goal is to persist this change permanently, then consider using this aggregation pipeline as [the second argument to the `update` command](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-with-aggregation-pipeline)